# Install .ini file With VB6 Setup

Tags: vb6

I have a vb6 app that is compiled referencing a .ini file in the project folder. I imported the file and its added as a module. Is this the best way to ensure the file is distributed with the setup? Ideally, the file should be stored in the app's folder in Program Files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Folders in Program Files aren't writable. Files like ini files go into `AppData\Appname`, which didn't exist in Win 98 (what VB6 was designed for).

In VB6's Setup program you can specify which files to add to setup and where to put them. But AppPath needs to be specified by a hardcoded path (maybe an `%AppData%\AppFolder`will work).

Add ini to setup, install it in ProgramFiles, if it doesn't exist in AppData, copy it over.

> C:\Users\User>icacls "%programfiles%"
>
> C:\Program Files NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller:(F)
>
> ```
>             NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller:(CI)(IO)(F)
>             NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(M)
>             NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)
>             BUILTIN\Administrators:(M)
>             BUILTIN\Administrators:(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)
>             **BUILTIN\Users:(RX)**
>             BUILTIN\Users:(OI)(CI)(IO)(GR,GE)
>             CREATOR OWNER:(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)
> ```
>
> Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files

Comment: I'm working on porting a VB6 app at my worksite. It uses an ini file that rides along with it in the C:\Program Files\ in Windows 7. System has no trouble updating it, or adding new entries (new sections, new section entries). So it is incorrect to say folders in Program Files aren't writable.

Comment: **BUILTIN\Users:(RX)**

Comment: @StarPilot : it depends on your UAC settings in windows. Most companies use a default setting that doesnt allow writing in folders inside Program Files

Comment: @Hrqls UAC settings only affect admins. Limited users can never write unless custom security settings are applied.

Comment: @BambiLongGone : I had a problem with files being in the AppData folders, but when I switched UAC off I could place them in the Program Files folders again ... I am local admin though, so that might be it (btw my app still worked with files being in the AppData folders, the users just couldnt find the log file anymore when they needed them :))

Comment: @Hrqls : Users should be able to write to the INI file that is located in the same directory as the running app, even with UAC enabled. We do it at my worksite with a system running VB6 apps that are being migrated to CSharp.Net. As long as the appropriate GetPrivateProfileString and SetPrivateProfileString Win32 api calls are being made, UAC won't get in the way, regardless of if the user is an admin or not. But if that ini file is located somewhere other than with the invoked app, I would expect it to be blocked by UAC.

Comment: It's blocked by Windows file security. **BUILTIN\Users:(RX)**.R means Read and X means Execute. Note no Write permissions.

Comment: If you dump INI files under the Program Files folder then whenever a Standard User tries to do an update a private virtualized *copy* is silently created for future use if Windows detects a legacy program.  For a program properly marked as non-legacy an access violation is reported.

Comment: @StarPilot : my app created a sub directory in the directory of the app named "logs" to store the log files ... its a communication app which stores all communication in a log file, so the users dont have to save it themselves ... but it took me some time to find it again when the UAC was active as it was moved to the AppData folders by the OS

Comment: @StarPilot : the complete directory was : c:\users\<username>\appdata\local\virtualstore\program files (86)

Answer (score 1):

Normally your installer would be run elevated and be sophisticated enough to create an application-specific folder under the LocalAppData special folder.  Then it would set appropriate security on that folder to permit standard users to read and write your INI file.  Finally it would deploy your INI file in that folder.

Your application would need to be sophisticated enough to locate that folder at runtime to use the INI file.

If you are using an installer technology without this flexibility it would be possible to look for the INI file as part of "first run detection."  If the file is missing it could rerun itself requiring elevation or spawn an elevated helper program to create the folder, set the appropriate security on it, and copy in the original INI file.

Failing to deal with folder security will be problematic since these locations inherit "owner" security where only the file creator has full read/write access.

None of that is new, these have been the rules for deployment since at least 1997 or so when IE4 delivered the Windows 95 Desktop Update.  People got away with murder under Win9x where there was no effective security at all and on NT until Vista by overusing Administrator and Power User accounts to bypass security to make it feel like Win9x.

None of this is unique to VB6 applications either.